# Is there a way to get Panache queries working in debugger using IntelliJ IDEA’s “Evaluate Query” function?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I started exploring Quarkus and Panache a few days ago, and the experience has been a blast so far. However, I can’t figure out how to run Panache queries using the “Evaluate Query” option in IntelliJ IDEA.

If I run my demo application using `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev`, all defined endpoints work properly and respond with the expected response. For example, my `ArticleResource` defines a method like so:

```java
@Path("/article")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ArticleResource {
    @GET
    public List<Article> getAll(@QueryParam @DefaultValue("0") Integer page) {
        return Article.findAll().page(Page.of(page, 2)).list();
    }
}
```

There is no problem with the data it returns when queried using `curl` or `http`. However, if I connect a debugger to the application, pause execution on a breakpoint in the `getAll` method and use the “Evaluate Expression” function on the `Article.findAll().page(Page.of(page, 2)).list()` expression, instead of database entities, an exception is thrown.

The exception type is `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, with a detail message of `This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses: did you forget to annotate your entity with @Entity?`.

I think the detail message is a red herring because my `Article` entity is annotated with the `@Entity` annotation for sure, and a relevant database table is created as well. I tried two ways of attaching the debugger to my application:

1. Define a custom `public static void main` method and run the app like a normal Java app from IDEA.
2. Have IDEA execute the `compile quarkus:dev` Maven goals, and define a remote debugger connection.

Both of those approaches result in the same exception being thrown. It also doesn’t seem to matter which Panache queries I try to evaluate, even a simple `Article.listAll()` call fails with the same exception.

I searched the documentation on topics such as Maven tooling, IDE integration and Panache, but haven’t found any mention of this issue. When searched for the exception details, most search results are related to people having this issue when running a test suite, not related to the debugger.

The JDK I tried using is GraalVM EE 20.1.0 (based on OpenJDK 11).

I hope my explanation was understandable, and thank you for any insight into this issue!

Comment: Panache methods are generated at build time via bytecode enhancement. Apparently, Intelij debugger didn't see the generated methods and you ends up with our default error message ...
Can you open an issue on Github ? Maybe we can do something about it.

Comment: Will do, thank you so much!